# Custom Button: Illegal Token error

Tags: visualforce, javascript, custom-button, java

I am trying to create a custom  button on a detail page that updates a field on the record. Here is my code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")} 

var newRecords = [];  

var idLob = new sforce.SObject(“Idea_Lobby__c”);  
idLob.id =”{!Idea_Lobby__c.Id}”;                  

idLob.Vote_Test__c =(’Up‘) ; 

newRecords.push(idLob);            

result = sforce.connection.update(newRecords); 
window.location.reload();
```

I get an illegal token error. Any ideas on what's going wrong? Also, can I call this button from a command button in a HTML visualforce page?

Thanks!

Comment: Is vote_Test__c a text val if so try idLob.Vote_Test__c = 
"Up" ;

Answer (score 1):

Did you copy the script from an editor? I am just noticing the slightly slanted inverted commas, sometimes the encoding for the inverted commas is also copied along with the text. Just guessing as the script seems otherwise fine :)

Answer (score 0):

The quotes were my problem. Here's the final code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")} 

var newRecords = [];  

var idLob = new sforce.SObject(“Idea_Lobby__c”);  
idLob.id =”{!Idea_Lobby__c.Id}”;                  

idLob.Vote_Test__c ="Up" ; 

newRecords.push(idLob);            

result = sforce.connection.update(newRecords); 
window.location.reload();
```

Thanks for everyone's help!